# Last login message on Ubuntu confusing. Security issue?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, putty

I am using Putty to SSH into my AWS EC2 machine. When I connect from my machine, exit again and reconnect again, it tells me that the last login was made from rrcs-24-199-207-171.midsouth.biz.rr.com? I know that last login was me but I have no clue where this url comes from? Is this something to worry about from a security perspective or is this an AWS thing?

Thank you very much for your advice.

Daniel

Comment: This is simply the reverse DNS of your IP address.

Comment: Reverse lookup of your IP; go to http://www.ipchicken.com/ and see if the address matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a roadrunner Time Warner DNS name.

Whenever your home router connects to the internet it gets a dynamic IP address.  That address has a DNS name that in your case is `rrcs-24-199-207-171.midsouth.biz.rr.com`.  Most providers use DNS names with dashes that describe their IP addresses so in essence your router public IP address is `24.199.207.171`